# continuous function, derivative with removable discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}f_1(x) & \mbox{if $x\leq 0$}\\
f_2(x) & \mbox{if $x>0$,}\end{array}\right.$  with the following assumptions:

1. $f$ is continuous through its domain.
2. $f_1$ is differentiable over $]-\infty,0[$.
3. $f_2$ is differentiable over $]0,+\infty[$.
4. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^-} f_1'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+} f_2'(x)=L$.

Can I conclude from this that $f'(0)$ exists and equals $L$?

Comment: No, take the function $f(x)=|x|$. In this case, $f_2(x)=-x$ and $f_1(x)=x$. They satisfy all the axioms. However, I wanna note that, as stated, assumption $1$ implies assumption $4$.

Comment: I am sorry, Conrad.  I made a mistake in assumption 4.  Now, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. By your definition of $f$, $f_1$ is defined on $]-\infty,0]$, and if $f_2$ is defined only on $]0,\infty[$ we can extend its definition continuously (by assumption 1) to $0$ by setting $f_2(0)=f_1(0)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ then there exist $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $x\in]-\delta_1,0]$, $$\left\vert\frac{f_1(x)-f_1(0)}{x}-L\right\vert<\varepsilon,$$ and similarly there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that for all $x\in[0,\delta_2[$, $$\left\vert\frac{f_2(x)-f_2(0)}{x}-L\right\vert<\varepsilon.$$

Define $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}>0$. Then for all $x\in]-\delta,\delta[$, $$\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-L\right\vert<\varepsilon,$$
as required.